# SVG pattern change color of hovered element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a background with SVG pattern and I only want change the color of the hovered item, not all.

I've tried to use :hover on my polygon tag but it doesn't work.

```css
svg:hover pattern polygon{
  fill:red;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0s;
}

polygon{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="stars" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
        <polygon points="50,9 60.5,39.5 92.7,40.1 67,59.5 76.4,90.3 50,71.9 23.6,90.3 32.9,59.5 7.2,40.1 39.4,39.5" fill="blue"/>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#stars)" />
  </svg>

</div>
```

Maybe I have to use JS but I don't know how.
It's the first time I work with SVG, I've searched on the web but can't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [stated by Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51495064/2898738), you wont be able to target individual pattern elements, but you can programmatically simulate the pattern:

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const X_OFFSET = 100;

for (let i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
  var useElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
  useElement.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', '#star');
  useElement.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + (X_OFFSET * i) + ' 0)');
 svg.appendChild(useElement);
}
```

```css
polygon:hover{
  fill:red;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0s;
}

polygon{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
      <polygon id="star" points="50,9 60.5,39.5 92.7,40.1 67,59.5 76.4,90.3 50,71.9 23.6,90.3 32.9,59.5 7.2,40.1 39.4,39.5" fill="blue"/>
    </defs>
  </svg>

</div>
```

[Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcrbx2qp/9/)

Comment: Which browser ?

Comment: OK I do confirm it's not working in Chrome (it is with Firefox), I'll check this out...

Comment: Little workaround waiting for a better solution : http://jsfiddle.net/6yzx8bar/2/

Comment: @Plum: thanks for your contribution! Here is another workaround consisting in cloning the star node instead of creating `use` nodes, but it's somehow taking us away from the original problem... https://jsfiddle.net/vcrbx2qp/33

Answer (score 0):

You can make them different elements:

```css
polygon:hover{
  fill:red;
  transition: 0s;
}

polygon {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <polygon points="50,9 60.5,39.5 92.7,40.1 67,59.5 76.4,90.3 50,71.9 23.6,90.3 32.9,59.5 7.2,40.1 39.4,39.5" fill="blue"/>
    <polygon points="50,9 60.5,39.5 92.7,40.1 67,59.5 76.4,90.3 50,71.9 23.6,90.3 32.9,59.5 7.2,40.1 39.4,39.5" transform="translate(100 0)" fill="blue"/>
    <polygon points="50,9 60.5,39.5 92.7,40.1 67,59.5 76.4,90.3 50,71.9 23.6,90.3 32.9,59.5 7.2,40.1 39.4,39.5" transform="translate(200 0)" fill="blue"/>
    <polygon points="50,9 60.5,39.5 92.7,40.1 67,59.5 76.4,90.3 50,71.9 23.6,90.3 32.9,59.5 7.2,40.1 39.4,39.5" transform="translate(300 0)" fill="blue"/>
  </svg>
```

Comment: It's OK if I have few elements but not if I have a lot of elements. I don't know how many elements I will have (maybe 50+) what's why I use a pattern

Comment: @Plum With pattern I don't think you can target item individually because it's a pattern and seen as one element